# Can I get Billing Agreement ID without onBoard?

Tags: rest, api, paypal, opencart, paypal-sandbox

I have a requirement to get billing agreement id without doing seller onBoard. And tie up billing agreement with express checkout method.

Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is this. If you need help send me a message. I'm doing PayPal Commerce integration right now (READ: last 2 months). https://developer.paypal.com/docs/limited-release/reference-transactions/#
I had a lot of implementation problems, poor documentation etc.